# Jersey CORS working for GET but not POST

Tags: java, jersey

My Jersey [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) request is not functioning for POST, but works for GET requests.  The headers are being mapped to Jersey requests as shown in the below screenshot of a GET request to the same resource.

However, doing a POST to the below method makes me end up with `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://production.local/api/workstation. Origin http://workstation.local:81 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

**Here's a screenshot of network activity:**
[image]

**Details on failed POST request:**
[image]

**Here's my resource:**

```
@Path("/workstation")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class WorkstationResource {

    @InjectParam
    WorkstationService workstationService;

    @POST
    public WorkstationEntity save (WorkstationEntity workstationEntity) {
        workstationService.save(workstationEntity);
        return workstationEntity;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getAllActive")
    public Collection<WorkflowEntity> getActive () {
        List<WorkflowEntity> workflowEntities = new ArrayList<WorkflowEntity>();
        for(Workflow workflow : Production.getWorkflowList()) {
            workflowEntities.add(workflow.getEntity());
        }
        return workflowEntities;
    }
}
```

**My CORS filter:**

```
public class ResponseCorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {

        Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.fromResponse(response.getResponse());
        responseBuilder
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD");

        String reqHead = request.getHeaderValue("Access-Control-Request-Headers");

        if(null != reqHead && !reqHead.equals(null)){
            responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHead);
        }

        response.setResponse(responseBuilder.build());

        return response;
    }
}
```

My Jersey configuration in my Main class:

```
//add jersey servlet support
ServletRegistration jerseyServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("JerseyServlet", new SpringServlet());
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.production.resource");
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters", "com.production.resource.ResponseCorsFilter");
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
jerseyServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
jerseyServletRegistration.addMapping("/api/*");
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Yes, and I've allowed cross origin.  Shouldn't that allow this to function correctly?

Comment: Don't know enough about the environment, just pointing out things that come to mind.  Maybe you missed something.

Comment: Is that first request you have shown the OPTIONS request or the POST/GET? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: @DMoses - The screenshot shows a GET, I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Can you validate that the OPTIONS returns the correct header.  Your browser should be doing an options request before throwing that error or sending the cors post.

Comment: @DMoses - It is running an OPTIONS header and that header is successfully providing the exact headers shown in the above screenshot.

Comment: can you try updating your filter to call out your origin `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://workstation.local:81");`.  If that works then you likely have some form of security on you post.  cookies or authentication header.

Comment: Also you should change your filter to append additional headers you want to accept instead of having two `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` lines.  That might cause an issue.

Comment: @DMoses - Changing the origin from `*` to that URL didn't produce any solutions.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a JSON mapping issue? I've found that I sometimes get very cryptic to little logging in the POJO mapping functions. Try adding a post method that with no object parameter and test a post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I thought this was a CORS issue, turns out it was a Jersey issue...

`org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler` on line 256 handles an exception...

```
    FilterChainInvoker filterChain = getFilterChain(request);
    if (filterChain != null) {
        filterChain.invokeFilterChain(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    } else {
        servletInstance.service(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "service exception:", ex);
    customizeErrorPage(response, "Internal Error", 500);
}
```

In my log, all I see is `service exception:` with nothing after it.  When I debug this line, I end up seeing the error `javax.servlet.ServletException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "workflowProcess": com.production.model.entity.WorkstationEntity#setWorkflowProcess(1 params) vs com.production.model.entity.WorkstationEntity#setWorkflowProcess(1 params)` which gives me something I can actually work with.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell and hard to debug since it's the *browser* that produces that error upon inspecting the response (header).

Even upon very close inspection your code looks fine and sane except that `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is or may be set twice in `filter()`. While [RFC 2616 (HTTP 1.1) Section 4.2](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.4.2.p.5) does basically permit it given certain conditions are met I wouldn't gamble here. You have no control over how browser X version N handles this.

Instead of setting the same header twice with different values rather append the 2nd set of values to the existing header.

Comment: I've made that change, unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue

Comment: If you could see me scratching my head....is the behavior consistent across all major browsers? Any chance you could enable debug logging in one of them e.g. [Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging)?

Comment: I've never used Chrome's debug logging before.  I'll investigate that.  Chrome is the only browser I'm supporting - it's an internal application used within the company.

Comment: Still, pls test with FF and IE to see if they show the same behavior - it's important to know.